# How to use backtracking to heuristically match value collections?

Tags: javascript

I have an interesting problem I'm not sure how to tackle. I'm fluent with backtracking type of functions, but I'm stumped by the following puzzle:

Suppose we have a collection of objects each of which defines an array of url parts, like `['/root', '/nested', '/nested', '/leaf']`. Given an array of url parts, find the object who's url parts match exactly. That's pretty easy, but here's the kicker: the url parts defined by the objects can be wildcards as well, like `['/root', '/:id', '/nested', ':name', '/leaf']`. Now it gets interesting, because an exact match is more important than a match against a wildcard, and exact matches should be followed as long as possible even though it will end with the most wildcards.

I imagine some recursion is needed with a heuristic function to appraise each route match. But I'm not sure how to start or how to make sure a valid match is always found if possible.

Here's what I am looking for:

```js
var objects =  [
  { id: 1, urlParts: ['/base', '/nested'] },
  { id: 2, urlParts: ['/base', '/nested', '/nested'] },
  { id: 3, urlParts: ['/base', '/nested', '/:name'] },
  { id: 4, urlParts: ['/base', '/other', '/:name'] },
  { id: 5, urlParts: ['/base', '/:name', '/nested', '/leaf'] },
  { id: 6, urlParts: ['/base', '/:id', '/nested', '/:leaf'] },
  { id: 7, urlParts: ['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/leaf'] },
  { id: 8, urlParts: ['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/:leaf'] }
];

console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base']) == null);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/nested']) == 1);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/nested', '/nested']) == 2);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/nested', '/other']) == 3);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/other']) == null);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/other', '/other']) == 4);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/another_name', '/nested', '/leaf']) == 5);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/1234', '/nested', '/variable']) == 6);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/a_name', '/whoops', '/leaf']) == null);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/leaf']) == 7);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/variable']) == 8);

function matchByUrlParts(urlParts) {
  return 'not implemented';
}
```

Any help is appreciated to get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a pattern string for each object which would have one character for each URL part it has. So such a pattern's string length would be the size of the `urlPart` array. Each character would be either "0" or "1". It should be "1" if the corresponding URL part is a wildcard.

**Example:** Given this object:

```
{ id: 6, urlParts: ['/base', '/:id', '/nested', '/:leaf'] },
```

The corresponding pattern would be:

```
"0101"
```

... where the "1" characters denote the positions of the wildcards.

The requirement that the search should try non-wildcard parts first, can be achieved by finding the match for which the pattern comes first in alphabetical order.

Since this pattern (cost) associated with an object does not depend on the input, but only on the *objects* array, you could calculate that before processing any input, and extend your objects with those patterns. Then you can sort the objects by that pattern.

With that in place you just have to find the first match for your input, and you'll know it is the optimal one (since you sorted the objects).

This ES6 function implements that idea:

```js
function preprocess() {
    objects.forEach( o => 
        o.pattern = o.urlParts.map( part => +part.startsWith("/:") ).join('')
    );
    objects.sort( (a, b) => a.pattern.localeCompare(b.pattern) );
}

function matchByUrlParts(input) {
    const found = objects.find( ({id, urlParts, pattern}) => {
        return urlParts.length == input.length
            && input.every( (part, i) => urlParts[i] == part || pattern[i] == "1") 
    });
    return found && found.id || null;
}

var objects =  [
  { id: 1, urlParts: ['/base', '/nested'] },
  { id: 2, urlParts: ['/base', '/nested', '/nested'] },
  { id: 3, urlParts: ['/base', '/nested', '/:name'] },
  { id: 4, urlParts: ['/base', '/other', '/:name'] },
  { id: 5, urlParts: ['/base', '/:name', '/nested', '/leaf'] },
  { id: 6, urlParts: ['/base', '/:id', '/nested', '/:leaf'] },
  { id: 7, urlParts: ['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/leaf'] },
  { id: 8, urlParts: ['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/:leaf'] }
];

preprocess();

console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base']) == null);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/nested']) == 1);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/nested', '/nested']) == 2);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/nested', '/other']) == 3);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/other']) == null);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/other', '/other']) == 4);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/another_name', '/nested', '/leaf']) == 5);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/1234', '/nested', '/variable']) == 6);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/a_name', '/whoops', '/leaf']) == null);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/leaf']) == 7);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/variable']) == 8);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Explanation

During the preprocessing the outcome of `part.startsWith("/:")` is converted to number with the unary `+`, yielding a 0 or 1. The `map` function returns an array of such 0 and 1 digits, which are then joined into a pattern string. This pattern is stored in the new `pattern` property of each original object. Then these objects are sorted by that new property using a `sort()` callback function.

The second function is then quite simple: it iterates through the sorted objects array with `find`, checking two conditions for each object:

- It should have just as many URL parts as the input has
- Each part should match or the corresponding object part should be a wildcard

`find` will stop iterating when a match is found and return the corresponding object. The function will then return the `id` property of that object, or `null` if there was no match.

#### About the pattern

The pattern of zeroes and ones can become very long. If objects and input would have like 100 URL parts, then this is no problem for this pattern system: a string can easily be 100 characters long and be compared. If however you would implement this with numbers, you'll bump into accuracy problems (because of the limited floating point precision).

Comment: I see it works, but I have a hard time parsing the code! Very cool though.

Comment: I added a section with an explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. I also posted my own version (after a good night sleep I had some ideas). I'm not sure which answer is the better one though. I'll run through your explanation section later today also. Again thanks!

Comment: I just saw your edit, that second solution makes much more sense to me and it's the fastest too. Maybe you should just use that as your main answer. Elegant too. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Following your suggestion, I have updated the answer to focus only on that "preprocessing" algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own version of an algorithm that seems to solve the problem:

```js
function matchByUrlParts(urlParts) {
  let lowest = objects.reduce((lowest, obj) => {
      var cost = obj.urlParts.length == urlParts.length && appraiseRouteCost(obj.urlParts, urlParts);
      var foundMatch = typeof cost == 'number' && !isNaN(cost);
      return (foundMatch && (!lowest || cost < lowest.cost) && {'obj':obj,'cost':cost}) || lowest;
    }, null);
  return lowest && lowest.obj.id;
}

function appraiseRouteCost(a, b, depth = 0) {
  var cost = a[depth] == b[depth] ? 0 : a[depth].startsWith('/:') && 10 ^ (a.length - depth) || undefined;
  return cost + (depth < a.length-1 ? appraiseRouteCost(a, b, depth + 1) : 0);
}

var objects =  [
  { id: 1, urlParts: ['/base', '/nested'] },
  { id: 2, urlParts: ['/base', '/nested', '/nested'] },
  { id: 3, urlParts: ['/base', '/nested', '/:name'] },
  { id: 4, urlParts: ['/base', '/other', '/:name'] },
  { id: 5, urlParts: ['/base', '/:name', '/nested', '/leaf'] },
  { id: 6, urlParts: ['/base', '/:id', '/nested', '/:leaf'] },
  { id: 7, urlParts: ['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/leaf'] },
  { id: 8, urlParts: ['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/:leaf'] }
];

console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base']) == null);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/nested']) == 1);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/nested', '/nested']) == 2);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/nested', '/other']) == 3);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/other']) == null);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/other', '/other']) == 4);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/another_name', '/nested', '/leaf']) == 5);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/1234', '/nested', '/variable']) == 6);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/a_name', '/whoops', '/leaf']) == null);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/leaf']) == 7);
console.log(matchByUrlParts(['/base', '/a_name', '/nested', '/variable']) == 8);
```

I find this solution a little more comprehensible than the other answer (of course this is subjective) and this one also performs [slightly better](https://jsperf.com/test-with-path-matching/1).

Comment: This algorithm is essentially the same as mine, with the difference that the cost is a numerical instead of a string (which I called "pattern"). The downside of using numbers is that for long arrays you would calculate a sum of a wide range of powers of 10, which at a certain limit would be victim of floating point inaccuracies. That is why I opted for strings, which do not have this limitation.